# XmlDocument OuterXml pretty printed

Tags: c#, xmldocument, pretty-print

I've got a XmlDocument and I want to get the Content (OuterXml) as a pretty printed string. How can I do this?

Regards

Comment: Do you need syntax highlighting or just indentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I understand this correctly

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@".....\test.xml");
string xDocString = xDoc.ToString(SaveOptions.None);
```

Comment: The "or you can use" link is dead